# How do i convert a python3.4 script(that has installed modules) into a windows executable using py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

I have a python script that i have to import all these modules, which some of them require downloading:

```
import datetime
from dateutil import parser
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter
import mailbox
import pprint
import json
import urllib.request
from tkinter import *
```

Is there a way, using py2exe, i can convert the script into a windows executable. If so, how?

Comment: You can  do it using a setyp.py script  http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the procedure, you will want to have all your modules already downloaded. This can be accomplished with a simple "pip install " from command prompt. Then it is as simple as writing and running a setup.py file - detailed directions for how to do this can be found [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial).